# Loop Cut Problem

Tags: subdivision-surface

For some reason with this particular mesh on this particular project, I can't seem to flatten out these faces with loop cuts.  I've done it for some other parts in this file and when I start a new one it works normally.  But for some reason it started doing this crap on this file at a certain point.  Can anyone tell me what's goin on here?

[image: very tiny gif]

Comment: From what I can make out in your extremely tiny gif (hint, hint), your support loop gets merged, so you need to disable "snap during transform" (magnet button).

Comment: That should be an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but it wasn't that.  Although it was a big clue and looking at the other buttons in that area, I found that I had the "Automatically merge vertices moved to the same location" button.  And sorry about the size of the gif.  I was in a rush to post this before I had to go to work, so I'll keep that in mind for next time.  Thanks for the help!